# Как при наличии определенного класса у одного элемента скрыть другой?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите новичку. Есть на странице кнопка, она создается с помощью скрипта с другого сервиса (виджет заказать звонок). У этой кнопки есть классы `lt-label` и `lt-online` или `lt-offline`. Создается она динамически и помещается в `body`.

Есть также статичная кнопка фиксированная.

Вопрос: как посредством js скрыть статичную кнопку, если у динамической есть класс `lt-offline`?

Пробовал так

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
        var redTags = document.getElementsByClassName('lt-label');
        if (redTags.is(".lt-offline")) {
            $("#l-b-wrapper").css({
                'display': 'none'
            });
        };
    };
});
```

Но не получается из-за того, что тут и просто js и jquery. Как мне сделать правильно?

Comment: вообще было бы неплохо пример разметки

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

`Jquery` предоставляет метод `hasClass`, который возвращает `true` если у элемент имеет нужный класс, `false` - если не имеет.

```
var $elem = $(".someClass");
$elem.hasClass("someClass"); // true
```

Ну и соответственно для вашего случая:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $redTags = $('.lt-label');
    if($redTags.hasClass(".lt-offline") {
        $("#l-b-wrapper").hide();
    }
}
```

`hide` - метод, которые скрывает элемент ( за место `css({display: "none"}) );`

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант с [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#l-b-wrapper").toggle($('.lt-label.lt-offline').length > 0);
});
```